# OpenCv Manager on Android 2.4.11

Tags: java, opencv, android-studio, android

I'm making a project using OpenCV on android android studio. I am using OpenCV library 3.0 because I made a project to calculate the image moments, but the library as Imgproc.Moments not exist in the library OpenCV 3.0 so I replaced it with a library 2.4.11, but the problem on 2.4.11 library OpenCV can not run with the existing manager on google play store, if anyone could help me to settle my problems? I need a pack OpenCV manager 2.4.11 to be able to run programs that I buatdi android from the android studio. Thank you before, I desperately need a solution.

Comment: please refer  https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5017

Comment: yes,thanks for your answer my quetion,but what if iam upgrade from library 3.0 to 3.1 my project can used on android with library 3.1?

Comment: You can. see whatisor commented on Mar 11 in the link

Comment: thanks @Kathi , i already at the public static Moments contourMoments in my imageproc.java project just like that coment on Mar 11 but i stil have a problem ,  
The moments text still have red colour (error) ,can you help me to solve the problem?hopefully someone can help me..